# Discrete dynamical system described by Dirichlet L-function using Yitang latest results on Landau–Siegel zero

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, chaos, landau-siegel-zeros

Using the following definition of Dirichlet L-function
$$
L(1,\chi)=\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{2\pi h}{w\sqrt{m}} &  \textit{if}\ \chi(-1)=-1 \\\\
\dfrac{2 h \log{|\epsilon|}}{w\sqrt{m}} &  \textit{if}\ \chi(-1)=1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
and [Theorem 4](https://mathoverflow.net/a/433988/51189) of Yitang Zhang latest results on Landau–Siegel zero, I have derived the 2 following discrete maps (I called them Yitang dynamics):
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{x_n}}+c\log(x_n)^{-\alpha},\quad \chi(-1)=-1 \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
with $x_n=m,n=0,1\dotsc$ and $\beta=\frac{2\pi h}{w}$ , $c$ is the constant of Yitang defined in his Theorem 4.

For the second case $\chi(-1)=1$, Yitang dynamics can be written as :
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{\beta \log(|\epsilon|)}{\pi\sqrt{x_n}}+c\log(x_n)^{-\alpha},\quad \chi(-1)=1. \tag{2}
$$
**Edit**: The discussion and analysis of this dynamics is montioned here [on my Wordpress blog](https://zeraouliamathematics.wordpress.com/2020/07/26/example-post-3/?fbclid=IwAR0drSbbbe3osBGjj-_e9HKZ1QSHjYkIfYSV2TRnooCafAs9V52K038RTjo)
and for more detail one can check my arXiv paper entitled  [New chaotic dynamics for Yitang Zhang latest results on Landau–Siegel zero](https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.12862).

Yitang discrete dynamics seems to have a fixed points converge to 0 as shown  in the below figure:

**Edit**: Some  Lyapunov exponents of Yitang dynamics (numerical data) for $\alpha$ in the range $(0,600)$ have been computed using Mathematica code available [here as a notebook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tAmUF5tTnibEonQsITHJszdlduCildHT/view?usp=share_link), see the interpreted data in the following plot:

[image]

Now my partial  questions here according to  the above analysis are:

> **Question**: Assume the dynamics \eqref{1} is reformulated correctly. Is there any relationship between analytical solutions of dynamics \eqref{1} and Landau–Siegel zero? Is it possible to  compute the entropy of that dynamics?  Does the chaotic behavior of this dynamics give any validity about Yitang latest results on Landau–Siegel zero?

**Note1**: for more explanation for  Entropy I want to compute is the entropy of [Kolmogorov Sinai](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kolmogorov-Sinai_entropy#:%7E:text=Kolmogorov%20introduced%20a%20new%20class,the%20theory%20of%20random%20processes.)it is known that Kolmogorov Sinai entropy $H_{KS}$ is bounded by the sum of positive Lyapunov exponents due to the [Margulis-Ruelle inequality](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Pesin_entropy_formula), I'm not able to get such closed form expression  for the values of Lypunove exponents I got [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tAmUF5tTnibEonQsITHJszdlduCildHT/view?usp=share_link) for getting the upper bound of Kolmogorov Sinai entropy , and my purpose for that is to know more about injectivity and bijectivity for Yitang dynamics.

**Note2**: the motivation behind this question is to predict such relationship between Landau–Siegel zeros and the analytical solution of the reformulated discrete dynamics.

**Reference:**

(1): [Dynamics of Riemann zeta function](https://mathoverflow.net/q/326721/51189)

(2): [Contribution of Yitang Zhang latest results if correct to correlation conjecture of H. L. Montgomery?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/434287/51189)

Comment: Should it be obvious that there's any connection at all? More specifically, why should that choice of $c$ be meaningful to the dynamics whatsoever? (plenty of dynamical systems exhibit regions of stability, so a more fundamental reason than that would be needed)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I didn't claimed that it should there is a clear connection (I aslo asked about that), since roughly the dynamics were derived  from the definition of L function and Theorem of Yitang latest on Landau siegle zero(please check the above linked theorem 4) and for c it is the effective absolute constant of yitang in His theorem that just positive you may need take it  as you want , you will get the same behavior and similar analyze.

Comment: For example, "entropy" can mean many things to different people. So it is better to write down the mathematical definition you have in mind.

Comment: MO is not really a place for presenting research. But if you get stuck on some technical question, please free to post it.

Comment: @ThomasKojar ,Thank you , I already wrote a priprint i submitted to arxiv 2 days ago , For Entropy i think it's clear that i mean entropy of discrete map which is less than or equal's sum of Lypunov exponents ,but am going to add some detail in the above question

Comment: Still you need to add more mathematical-symbols and definitions (eg. of entropy) in your questions. These current questions seem open-ended.

Comment: @ThomasKojar, Thanks for your attention .am going to add this

Comment: For example, if you are trying to prove some math-theorem, specify any steps that you are stuck on. eg. "I tried to compute the entropy using Lyapunov exponents, but I got stuck at getting an upper bound here."

Comment: @ThomasKojar, I wish what i have added about entropy for more clarification is enough

Comment: We will see what experts think. It wouldn't hurt to add some of your own mathematical-attempts to get that upper bound/closed-expression you mention and explaining what mathematical/technical issues arise. The more math symbols you add, the more concrete your questions will be.

Comment: @ThomasKojar ,am still awaiting their comments .unfortunately i have got no comment even now ,I sent a copy of my arxiv paper to Yitang Zhang and i wish to receive his comments to improve my paper.

Comment: MO is more about answering specific technical questions and less about presenting research or conjectures ("does A relate to B?"). If you try to prove some theorem and you get stuck, please feel free to post here.

Comment: @ThomasKojar, That is just few results not all research  , I think that is allowed to discuss results by presenting partial questions , look for example Yitang Zhang results are presented in the context of partial questions, I already added them as reference